# In Kendo UI MVC, how do I put a tabstrip in a window using javascript?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window, kendo-tabstrip

In my view page, I have a button. When I click the button, I want to make the window open. The window  has some tabstrips, and in the tabstrip I want to show a grid. Does kendo UI allow me to do this?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("window")
.Title("About Alvar Aalto")
.Content(@<text>  
 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
      .Name("tabstrip")
      .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
          tabstrip.Add().Text("Paris")
              .Selected(true)
              .Content(@<text>
                <div class="weather">
                    <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                    <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
                </div>
                <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
              </text>);

          tabstrip.Add().Text("New York")
              .Content(@<text>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
         .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
    )
   )
  </text>);
      })
     )
  </text>)
 .Draggable()
 .Resizable()
 .Width(600)
 .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
 .Events(ev => ev.Close("onClose"))
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Best thing for you to do is to split this into some Partial Views to make your life a little less complicated.

**Kendo Window**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("window")
    .Title("About Alvar Aalto")
    .Content(@Html.Partial("_TabStrip").ToHtmlString())
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(600)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
    .Events(ev => ev.Close("onClose"))
```

)

**_TabStrip** (Partial View)

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
.Name("tabstrip")
.SelectedIndex(0)
.Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add()
            .Text("Paris")
            .Content(@Html.Partial("_Weather").ToHtmlString());
        items.Add()
            .Text("New York")
            .Content(@Html.Partial("_Grid").ToHtmlString());
    })    
)
```

**_Weather** (Partial View)

```
 <div class="weather">
     <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
     <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
  </div>
 <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
```

**_Grid** (Partial View)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
         .Refresh(true)
         .PageSizes(true)
         .ButtonCount(5))
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
        )
   )
```

Separating out the content by using Partial Views will allow you greater flexibility with pulling the content with Kendo controls within each other and not have to worry about getting the <text> blocks correct.

Comment: Hi,I wonder if I use Partial Views like this '.Content(@Html.Partial("_Grid").ToHtmlString());',will my grid event work?

Comment: Can you tell me how to write your code using javascript?I have to pass dynamic parameter to the tabStrip.I can not write them in  this formate:'.Content(@Html.Partial("_Weather").ToHtmlString());'.

Answer (score 0):

The grid events and such are localized to their respective partial view much like it was a full view.  Partial views can take their own model separate from the parent view which allows greater flexibility in an mvc app.